# return new ModelAndView redirect does not work for some reason

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, redirect, modelandview

I'm really new to Spring MVC framework and I'm in desperate need of help right now.

For some reason, my redirect does not work its giving me HTTP Status 400, with no error on console that is why it is very hard to debug.

Scenario:
I have 2 forms. The first form is saving properly then redirects to 2nd form, but when I repeat my code to pass it to the 3rd form I get an http 400 error. I'm pretty sure I replicated what I used on the first form.

View:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="kiosk"
                action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/kiosk/kiosk-initial-info-save.html">
<div align="center">
    <br /> 
    <div id="addKioskContainer">
    <div class="datagrid1" align="center" style="width: 33%;">
        <table align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">Initial Information</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3 align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;You are applying for <label style="color: blue;">Restructured Loan</label> in <label style="color: blue;">Eastwood.</label></h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <div id="initialInfoContainer">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                        <b>Purpose of Loan: </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="loanPurpose" size="40"></form:input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="applicantInfoContainer">
                <div class="datagrid2" align="center" style="width: 95%;">
                    <table align="center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">Applicant's Information</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>Last Name: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="appLastName" size="40"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>First Name: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="appFirstName" size="40"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>Middle Name: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="appMiddleName" size="40"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>Birthdate: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="appBirthDate" size="20"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>w/ Comaker: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:checkbox path="withCoMaker"></form:checkbox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="comakerInfoContainer">
                <div class="datagrid2" align="center" style="width: 95%;">
                    <table align="center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">Comaker's Information</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>Last Name: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="comakerLastName" size="40"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>First Name: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="comakerFirstName" size="40"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>Middle Name: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="comakerMiddleName" size="40"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12px;" >
                                <b>Birthdate: </b><label style="color: red;">*</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="comakerBirthDate" size="20"></form:input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div align="center">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Next" id="btnProceedKiosk"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "/kiosk-initial-info", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public ModelAndView initialInfoKioskPage()
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView( "kiosk-initial-info" );

    modelAndView.addObject( "kiosk", new Kiosk() );

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/kiosk-initial-info-save", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public ModelAndView saveInitialInfo( @ModelAttribute
Kiosk kiosk )
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView( "kiosk-initial-info" );

    modelAndView.addObject( "kiosk", new Kiosk() );

    return new ModelAndView( "redirect:/kiosk/kiosk-initial-info.html" );
}
```

Model:

```
    package com.etel.kiosk.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "kioskmain" )
public class Kiosk
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String loanType;

    private String branch;

    private String loanPurpose;

    private String appLastName;

    private String appFirstName;

    private String appMiddleName;

    private Date appBirthDate;

    private Boolean withCoMaker;

    private String comakerLastName;

    private String comakerFirstName;

    private String comakerMiddleName;

    private Date comakerBirthDate;

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Integer id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLoanType()
    {
        return loanType;
    }

    public void setLoanType( String loanType )
    {
        this.loanType = loanType;
    }

    public String getBranch()
    {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch( String branch )
    {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    public String getLoanPurpose()
    {
        return loanPurpose;
    }

    public void setLoanPurpose( String loanPurpose )
    {
        this.loanPurpose = loanPurpose;
    }

    public String getAppLastName()
    {
        return appLastName;
    }

    public void setAppLastName( String appLastName )
    {
        this.appLastName = appLastName;
    }

    public String getAppFirstName()
    {
        return appFirstName;
    }

    public void setAppFirstName( String appFirstName )
    {
        this.appFirstName = appFirstName;
    }

    public String getAppMiddleName()
    {
        return appMiddleName;
    }

    public void setAppMiddleName( String appMiddleName )
    {
        this.appMiddleName = appMiddleName;
    }

    public Date getAppBirthDate()
    {
        return appBirthDate;
    }

    public void setAppBirthDate( Date appBirthDate )
    {
        this.appBirthDate = appBirthDate;
    }

    public Boolean getWithCoMaker()
    {
        return withCoMaker;
    }

    public void setWithCoMaker( Boolean withCoMaker )
    {
        this.withCoMaker = withCoMaker;
    }

    public String getComakerLastName()
    {
        return comakerLastName;
    }

    public void setComakerLastName( String comakerLastName )
    {
        this.comakerLastName = comakerLastName;
    }

    public String getComakerFirstName()
    {
        return comakerFirstName;
    }

    public void setComakerFirstName( String comakerFirstName )
    {
        this.comakerFirstName = comakerFirstName;
    }

    public String getComakerMiddleName()
    {
        return comakerMiddleName;
    }

    public void setComakerMiddleName( String comakerMiddleName )
    {
        this.comakerMiddleName = comakerMiddleName;
    }

    public Date getComakerBirthDate()
    {
        return comakerBirthDate;
    }

    public void setComakerBirthDate( Date comakerBirthDate )
    {
        this.comakerBirthDate = comakerBirthDate;
    }

}
```

DaoImpl

```
public void updateKiosk( Kiosk kiosk )
{
    Kiosk kioskToUpdate = getKiosk( kiosk.getId() );
    kioskToUpdate.setBranch( kiosk.getBranch() );
    kioskToUpdate.setLoanPurpose( kiosk.getLoanPurpose() );
    kioskToUpdate.setAppLastName( kiosk.getAppLastName() );
    kioskToUpdate.setAppFirstName( kiosk.getAppFirstName() );
    kioskToUpdate.setAppMiddleName( kiosk.getAppMiddleName() );
    kioskToUpdate.setAppBirthDate( kiosk.getAppBirthDate() );
    kioskToUpdate.setWithCoMaker( kiosk.getWithCoMaker() );
    kioskToUpdate.setComakerLastName( kiosk.getComakerLastName() );
    kioskToUpdate.setComakerFirstName( kiosk.getComakerFirstName() );
    kioskToUpdate.setComakerMiddleName( kiosk.getComakerMiddleName() );
    kioskToUpdate.setComakerBirthDate( kiosk.getComakerBirthDate() );
    getCurrentSession().update( kioskToUpdate );
}
```

Your answers will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Turn your logs to debug level.